# boost asio: How to monitor that a tcp connection is alive

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have a asynchronous TCP/IP client using asio. When the connection is lost, my handle function of async_read recieve an error. So I'm informed that a connection is lost.

Now, I'm refactoring some legacy codes implementing a synchronous TCP/IP client where the abstract interface enforces this sequence:  a synchronous write, then a synchronous read.
Doing that with asio is fairly easy, but I would like to know asynchronously if the connection is lost.

Is there a more elegant way than:

**Option A:**
Add a thread that checks if the socket is still alive (by trying to read... but how can I be sure that the read doesn't steal data from my synchronous read ? See [Boost asio ip tcp iostream Error Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040319/boost-asio-ip-tcp-iostream-error-detection))

**Option B:**
Use async_read instead and and emulate a synchronous read

Comment: I think the answer is no. Maybe there are some platform specific solutions though.

Comment: I don't think the TCP protocol can detect a connection failure unless it fails to receive an acknowledgement to sent packets within a certain time frame.

Comment: I've implemented option B. But, there are 2 things I don't understand 1. disconnections are not detected and 2. If I unplugged the ethernet cable of the server (that is a printer), I can still send it data and it returns no error. Only the second time, it will throw an error

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine that the synchronous operation would fail just like the asynchronous one would. It might be more disruptive when the synchronous one fails though, since the timeout could be very long and much more noticeable when everything else has to wait on it.

You might want to look into enabling TCP keep-alives on your socket, and possibly lower the TCP keep alive interval, to detect a lost connection sooner.

Comment: Worth mentioning; there are some limitations to TCP-keepalive, most notably there is no portable way (to my knowledge) to set the timeout of the keepalive. Also, the default timeouts are quite large; for example, on Linux, the default keepalive interval is 2 hours, and 9 probes must fail before the connection is deemed dead.

Comment: The essence is, in most cases, you must resort to dealing with connection timeout yourself in your application-code, adding "heartbeat"-checks to the protocol if possible, and trying to figure sane defaults for timeouts. ("Should this operation really ever take 5 seconds?", etc.")